# What are the passive form of these sentences?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

1. They were listening to the instructions carefully
2. I need a paint brush
3. The shops were always very busy
4. The vicar heard the news
5. The vicar grew old
6. He stood near the door wearing a black robe
7. He lived in a city
8. Mr. Jackson did things the new way
9. You must find a new verger

I know that this is a pretty amateur question. I have answered most of them. I was having second thoughts after finishing those so I just wanted to review everything.

Thank you for helping.....

Comment: what kind of passive form are you expecting for intransitive verbs ?

Comment: @Graffito if you think it is impossible then you can also mention that.

Comment: @R Please read the guidance on [homework](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/333/how-to-deal-with-homework-questions) previously suggested and make this question conform. Also, we are not your teachers and do not provide practice examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those sentences that have a transitive verb, you can get the passive voice by making the direct object the subject, using the passive form of the verb, and specifying what was the subject as the actor.

For the first sentence, you can put the adverb in a few different places. The following feels most comfortable to me, but others may put it somewhere else.

> They were listening to the instructions carefully.
>   The instructions were being carefully listened to by them.

The second sentence sounds awkward in the passive voice because it makes it sound like you need a *particular* paintbrush. However, if your boss needed you or a client needed you, it wouldn't sound as awkward.

> I need a paintbrush.
>   A paintbrush is needed by me.

The third sentence is not using a transitive verb, so it cannot be turned into passive voice.

> The shops were always very busy.

The fourth sentence is straightforward enough...

> The vicar heard the news.
>   The news was heard by the vicar.

The fifth sentence is not using a transitive verb, so it cannot be turned into passive voice.

> The vicar grew old.

The sixth sentence is fairly straightforward, but there are two verbs. However, "stood" isn't transitive, meaning it can't be turned into passive voice, so we turn "wear" into passive voice while incorporating the construction with "stood".

> He stood near the door wearing a black robe.
>   A black robe was worn by him as he stood near the door.

The seventh sentence feels awkward because we're talking about a city with, presumably, a lot of other people. If we were talking about a building, a house, or something smaller, it wouldn't be as awkward.

> He lived in the city.
>   The city was lived in by him.

Here's the eighth sentence.

> Mr. Jackson did things the new way.
>   Things were done the new way by Mr. Jackson.

And the ninth sentence is again a bit awkward much the way the second sentence was awkward.

> You must find a new verger.
>   A new verger must be found by you.

Comment: Thanks the explanation was really good. My doubts regarding the sixth one have been cleared, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All passives would be extremely awkward, but ...

1. The instructions were being listened to carefully by them.
2. A paint brush is needed by me.
3. [impossible]
4. The news was heard by the vicar.
5. [impossible]
6. A black robe was worn by him as the door had been stood near by him.
7. The city was lived in by him.
8. Things were done the new way by Mr. Jackson.
9. A new verger must be found by you.

Comment: I think you got 6 and 7 wrong. BTW could you give mesome similar conversions?

Comment: For 6) perhaps: *He stood near the door, a black robe weared by him*. And for 4), it's "were".

Comment: I think 6 is impossible too.

Comment: If you search for "active to passive conversions", you'll find a lot. For example: http://www.grammarly.com/answers/questions/68057-converter-active-to-passive/